# How to enable screen time offfunctionality in Android through AOSP customization

Tags: android, android-source

I am using Android-30 and I need to enable/disable auto-dim functionality for the whole device from our default application. If it is enabled after 10minutes of inactivity the screen will turn off, and if it is disabled the screen will stay on forever.

public static final String DIM_SCREEN of Settings.System class has been deprecated.

```
Settings.System.putLong(
                context.contentResolver,
                Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT,
                timeOut.toLong()
            )
```

The above code is not working. I have checked in framework/base/packages/SettingsProvide/res/values/default.xml and changed "def_screen_off_timeout" to 10000. But still the deivice is not going to turn off. Some amount of brightness is visible.

What is the current proper way to enable/disable screen timeout feature in Android for the whole device ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different things here. Auto Brightness (Adaptive Brightness) and screen off time are different things.

For screen timeout:

How are you testing the def_screen_off_timeout value? Since this is the default value - can get changed if user overrides it later using this method itself.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, time);
```

where time is the value in ms.

Then to alter the screen brightness value, you can set the adaptive brightness mode to Manual via [SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE) key and then set the value for [SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS) .

For all these to work, your app would need [WRITE_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_SETTINGS) permission.

Comment: Hi Rajat,

Thank you for your inputs. But when I am calling this:
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, time);
with proper permission, the screen is not turning to full dark. Do you mean after calling the previous method again I need to set "SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS" ? But then again on user interaction I think I need to set "SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS" again. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you share some project source code?